# start RPI on read only with Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, gui, readwrite

I want to start my RPI in read only mode to get a perfect 24/7use setup.But I need to have a graphical user interface running. For that I tried [this](https://wiki.somakeit.org.uk/wiki/Read_Only_Raspbian) guideline to put the SD card in read only mode. But my RPI is running in an erorr on booting and stops there:
`[0.687653] ---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(179,2) ]---`

While creating a new second partition the terminal is asking if I want to remove the ext4 signature. I tried to keep it AND to remove it so that should not be the problem.
I did not find an other guideline to set up the "writeprotection" with a GUI but maybe someone knows why this error occurs.
I'm using a RPI 4 with the latest version of Raspbian.

Comment: *"I want to start my RPI in read only mode to get a perfect 24/7use setup"* -> Quick piece of advice: As you are already getting some clues about, doing this will be **more** headache, not less.  Note that setting the system RO does *not* free you from the risk of filesystem corruption if the power is cut arbitrarily.  However, since a RO system is fine for you, you obviously don't need to do continuous large transfers to/from the card, so the risk is really not that great to start with.

Comment: ...I've run pi's 24/7 for years as have many of the regulars here (sometimes without even a shutdown for hundreds of days), I do not see any advantage in a RO system and many potential hassles.  The truly "perfect" goal to aim for is streamlined setups/backups, and a strategy for automating restores. However, "optimization is the root of all evil" and this is something that it is best to take some time to work out -- which is  to say you do not need to drop everything, pi wise, until them.  Just start investigating backup methodologies and, if your setup is elaborate, configuration management.

Comment: As per @goldilocks - its a lot of pain for little result (power or WAN link fails defeated me in the end).  You could try http://www.tinycorelinux.net for an in-memory Linux but I'm not sure if its fully up and running on the Pi 4 yet.

Comment: "*this guidline*" is a big one. What does it do? You may consider to use a union filesystem intead.

Comment: @goldilocks so you mean that for the lifetime of the SD Card it has the same result like stopping all the logs?

Comment: It's an oddly contentious topic: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/84905/25985 Based on my observations here, it seems that not everybody has a serious problem with SD card corruption/wear-out on the Pi.  Even more interesting, as far as I can tell, there is little or no broader problem amongst consumers -- yet micro SD cards are used in far, far, far more things than Raspberry Pi's.  So why is it that just a subset of Raspberry Pi users have this problem? Is it because everyone else prefers to ignore it?  Or is it because they are habitually doing something else wrong and do not recognize it?